# Vulkan: What could be causing very poor fps on an AMD card, but OK fps on an NVIDIA card

Tags: vulkan

I am part of a team working on a 3D game engine which has a vulkan rendering system. So far we have been testing on NVIDIA graphics cards, like the GTX 970 and have had decent performance.
But recently we tested a scene on an AMD card and got really low fps:

For example, rendering a sponza scene:
AMD R9 Fury: 5 fps
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970: 64 fps

The NVIDIA fps is not great, but much better than on AMD.

Do you guys have any idea what could be causing this difference in fps on the AMD card?
Or do you know how I could go about isolating what is causing the low fps on the AMD card?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You expect us to crystal ball you the solution? try and reduce the issue to a small example where the difference is still visible.

Comment: Is that behavior consistent between different OSes? (ex: Windows vs Linux) If you can't reproduce it on another OS, it could just be a bad driver

Comment: Are you using lots of unique bound `vkDeviceMemory` values per frame? Eg. you have 100 textures all with their own `vkAllocateMemory` calls?

Comment: This is probably bad question for SO format (too broad, and opinion-based with the lack of information you volunteered). Maybe [Vulkan forum](https://forums.khronos.org/forumdisplay.php/114-Vulkan)? Even so you need to provide bit more info about your program.

Comment: @KABoissonneault right now I'm just testing on Windows.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito yeah we probably have a lot of textures with their own uniquely bound memory. I'll look into it further.

Comment: Could be anything, but one thing I've heard is that AMD is sensitive to image layouts whereas NVidia basically ignores them. Are you using the VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL layout everywhere? If so, perhaps that causes poor performance.

Answer (score 1):

AMD drivers have issues when accessing numerous `vkDeviceMemory` values per submission. This is particularly a problem on Windows 7/8, which do not have WDDM 2.0. In fact, if you use too many (~1000) on Window 7, it is easy to reproduce a BSOD. Nvidia drivers seem to be doing something behind the scenes, and aren't subject to these limitations. However, as a result, their driver implementation may be hiding some opportunity for optimization from the user.

Regardless, the recommendation is to pool your memory allocations, such that `VkImage` and `VkBuffers` are allocated from the same segmented `vkDeviceMemory`. There is a open source library, called [Vulkan Memory Allocater](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/VulkanMemoryAllocator) which attempts to aid in implementing this behavior (and it is suspiciously authored by AMD!).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'll look into this.